# Error upon opening terminal in Ubuntu in relation to pythons vitualenv

Tags: python, ubuntu

Yesterday I installed pythons Virtualenv. Now every time I open a terminal I receive this error.

`mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/riley/.virtualenvs’: File exists`

Why Is it trying to create this directory every time I open a terminal?

Comment: Did you add anything to your `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, and/or `~/.bashrc` file?

Comment: Try deleting the file `.virtualenvs`? I'm not sure how you installed it but `virtualenv` is supposed to be in your Python directory like `pip`. Bottom line: I don't know the solution, this is just a suggestion

Comment: removing the .virtualenv file fixed the problem. I'm not sure why it was their in the first place. I did not intentionally create it. And no, there is nothing new in my `$PATH` files. Thanks for the help